# omniauth-facebook namespace trace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, rubygems

I saw this code at omniauth-facebook/lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb

```
require 'omniauth/strategies/oauth2'
require 'base64'
require 'openssl'
require 'rack/utils'

module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class Facebook < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

The question is where is the namespace "`OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2`", which is inherited by `class Facebook` coming from?

Comment: From `omniauth` gem, no?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev tried tracing it. This is where I end up. https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/developer.rb
Maybe I'm just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code runs fine, then your `Gemfile` likely includes `omniauth-oauth2` gem. This is where it's defined: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb

Comment: Yup. That's it. Namespacing of ruby gems is kinda confusing when tracing.